# Nodejs get subfolders list

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, directory, fs

I need to get for specific path of all the subfolders, I've tried with the following

```
p = '/Users/i099566/projects/mp'
```

and under `mp` folder there is `sub-folders/folders`, which I want to get (not files)

When use the following code I got `null`, any idea what am I missing here?

```
const { readdirSync, statSync } = require('fs')
const { join } = require('path')

const dirs = (p: any) => readdirSync(p).filter((f: any) => statSync(join(p, f)).isDirectory())
console.log(dirs)
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `console.log(dirs(p))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `dirs` is a function that takes a parameter of type `any` that is called p.
With `console.log(dirs)` you are printing the function and do not call it in any way.
If you remove `(p: any) =>` and define the variable p before it should work as then `dirs` stores the results of the expressions of the right side instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
const { lstatSync, readdirSync } = require('fs')
const { join } = require('path')

const isDirectory = source => lstatSync(source).isDirectory()
const getDirectories = source =>
  readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory)
```

Check this code sample! Hope this will fix your issue.